# Python - Panda3D - Display HTML/CSS elements into Panda3D scene

Tags: python, html, css, panda3d

My hello message is not visible...

I'm writing a 3D video game using **Python** (3.10) language with **Panda3d** (1.10) as 3D game engine.

Some graphical parts of the game are not 3D, there are just 2D elements:

- spell bar,
- player resume
- quest panel
- skill tree
- etc
- spells/attacks book
- and others

I see on the web that pictures are used to styling Panda3D Direct* components.
However, in my opinion, I think use statics pictures (.png for exemple) is not efficient when game design must be evolved. That's why I prefer use HTML/CSS to render 2D elements, especially since CSS is very powerful if you know how to use it. I prefere to use SVG into the scene but I don't understand how create SVG file.

So, my question is:
**Can I use HTML/CSS inside a Panda3d application?**

Thank to all!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a workaround (temporary).

- I create HTML/CSS file that styling my 2D component that must be injected inside the Panda3D scene
- I create a Python script that convert an HTML part as PNG picture using RGBA for transparency
- I use the generated PNG picture inside my Panda3D scene on the target component.

It's not pure HTML/CSS, but it can works.